# individual user profile on click of user name in view

Tags: views, 7, theming, users, dashboard

I have a view of displaying uploaded image content by different users.
The content is displaying in box in below manner..
i.uploaded image
ii.title of the image
iii.user name and profile picture
iv.category

Now i want that
1. when the user clicks on either image or title one popup will open in a lightbox. in that popup the content should be the node content with all details.
I have done successfully with the module lightbox2 only to popup image but i want that particular node content in that popup.

2.After click on user name or profile picture that page goes to the particular users page with their details and their upload content.
Till now when i click on this link that particular user details opens in tab. but i want either all tabs merge in to one page or the things will display like i expained above.

please help me i am working it on since last 1 week but i am unable to find any solution..

please help/guide me ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Colorbox Node](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) to open particular node content in popup. This module gives the user the ability to display ANY page inside a colorbox modal without the header and footer.

It can be integrated with views also.

Views Integration with node colorbox modal
[image: View Integration with colorbox modal]

Comment: Thanks For ur reply but how to use it in view please elaborate i am stuck after installing the colorbox and colorbox-node module.

and what about click on username if you any idea please let me know.

Comment: @asalug Check updated answer.

Comment: hi rupesh, i did that but its still not working..